# which one of these units is not located in the microprocessor?

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, register

I'm doing a test on general computer science and I think the answer sheet is wrong. The question is as follows:

> which one of these units is not located in the microprocessor?
>
> 1) Cache memory
>
> 2) RAM
>
> 3) Control unit
>
> 4) 2 and 3

I think option 2 is the right one but the answer sheet has marked option 4
But regarding the image:

[image]

I insist on my answer. Am I wrong?

Comment: I agree with you, in the Van Neumann architechure (which us usually what they teach). The "Control Unit" is the Little Man in the LMC.

Answer (score 0):

> Control unit may refer to:
>
> - Control unit, a component of a computer's central processing unit
>
>   The control unit is a component of a computer's central processing unit (CPU) that directs operation of the processor. It tells the computer's memory, arithmetic/logic unit and input and output devices how to respond to a program's instructions.
> - Another name for a Controller
>
>   In computing and especially in computer hardware, a Controller is a chip, an expansion card, or a standalone device that interfaces with a peripheral device.

<sub>**Source:** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_unit_%28disambiguation%29)</sub>

Comment: This is a bit of a trick question because strictly worded the control unit *may* not be located in the microprocessor, but the usage of *is not located* in the question is ambiguous because control unit may refer to either a separate chip or a component of the CPU.

Comment: Also, no cache needs to be located on a CPU die. I used plenty of systems with a L1 cache optional on the motherboard (optional as in sockets for the SRAM were provided, but not filled).